# how to get the facebook profile picture in my android application?

Tags: android

I am developing a application in android in which i have to get the
facebook photo in to my application.

Is it possible in android?

please help me.

Thanks and Regards,
durgesh Limbani

Comment: i found ans of my this question.  i m using graph api. link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 11):

All you need is the user ID for the user, then you can call a function like this:

```
/**
 * Function loads the users facebook profile pic
 * 
 * @param userID
 */
public Bitmap getUserPic(String userID) {
    String imageURL;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading Picture");
    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Loading Picture FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

You can change the type in the imageURL to get different size pictures.

Answer (score 10):

For those still wandering:
Using the facebook SDK, you can implement a `ProfilePictureView` in your xml as shown:

```
<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:is_cropped="true"
    app:preset_size="small" />
```

And then, once you have your user's ID (have to make a request to get that one, but that's another story), you can get the `ProfilePictureView` itself and call:

```
    ProfilePictureView profilePicture = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    profilePicture.setProfileId(userID);
```

Where `userID` is a `String` containing the user's ID you have requested from facebook.

Comment: But this view is not flexible at all. If you want a circular image for example.

Comment: Can you please share how can i display circular  image.I have searched alot but did not found anything.

Comment: I've used this to get the picture on initial login, with the facebook SDK, but I'm not sure how to bring it back every time the app is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible (sorry, you're asking a yes/no question :))

Use the facebook android sdk, generate a new facebook app id and all that jazz. Then, in your app, you must ask the user for permission to access his profile data, from there you can, using the graph api, get the profile picture.

If you need help with more specific steps, ask specific questions.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can i display rounded image in facebook ProfilePictureView .

Answer (score 1):

```
private void saveFacebookProfilePicture(final String userID){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
             URL imageUrl = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large");
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
              FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),ProfileEditActivity.PROFILE_PIC));
              bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, ""+e.getMessage());
            }



        }
    }).start();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Facebook API, Facebook data can be fetched from that.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-androidfacebookapi/
Check this link.

Comment: the facebook class is deprecated in facebook 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Your Layout activity_facebook_main as

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
                android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                facebook:preset_size="small" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and your FacebookMainActivity code as

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;

public class FacebookMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_main);

            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {             

                                ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);
                                profilePictureView.setCropped(true);
                                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());

                                TextView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);                                                     
                                Name.setText(user.getName());

    }
                          }
                        }).executeAsync();
                    }               
                }
            });
        }   

    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
}
```