# How to get profile picture of user in facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get profile picture and User Name  of user which login in android app and set in Imageview

i am not getting how to get profile picture.

Thanks Advance

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706977/how-to-get-the-facebook-profile-picture-in-my-android-application and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094609/android-getting-all-users-friend-profile-pictures-quicly

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245654/593709)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the facebook ProfilePictureView instead of an image view:

```
<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
   android:id="@+id/friendProfilePicture"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:padding="5sp"
   facebook:preset_size="small" />
```

You can set the size to small/normal/large/custom.

Then in your code, set the user facebook id like this:

```
ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePicture);
profilePictureView.setProfileId(userId);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What is userId and i have also get User name?

Comment: When you get logged to facebook, you get an User object in callback.
You can found the facebook user id in this object:
user.getId();
To get name information you can use those functions: user.getFirstName(); user.getLastName(); user.getName();

Comment: 04-29 20:42:14.480: W/System.err(11630): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://graph.facebook.com/1251935507/pictures
getting this exception while getting profile picture if user:

Comment: @DamienR. Hey is that a library that i should include in my build.gradle?