# Upload facebook image into imageview

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-layout, android-activity

I have managed to have the user upload their picture from their device gallery to an imageview. However, I am trying to provide the user the ability to upload their profile picture from their facebook to an imageview.

Below is how I got to upload a picture from device gallery to imageview,

```
 Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

} 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }
```

I am trying to figure out ways so that when a user press the button "btnFacebookUpload" they are able to chose a picture from their facebook gallery which would be cast to the imageview "profilePicturePreview"

Update:

```
 Button buttonFacebookLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebookUpload);
    buttonFacebookLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
            profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);

            buttonFacebookLoadImage.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        @Override
                        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                                Exception exception) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                                    Response response) {
                                                if (user != null) {
                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());

                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }



    });
```

Problem:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable buttonFacebookLoadImage inside an inner class defined in a different method

in line

```
buttonFacebookLoadImage.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
```

also

Cannot refer to a non-final variable profilePictureView inside an inner class defined in a different method

in line

```
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
```

TAG cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You can use facebook graph Api to parse the user's profile pic url. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706977/how-to-get-the-facebook-profile-picture-in-my-android-application) may help you

Answer (score 1):

Use FB Sdk [You can download from here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)
Add it to ypur project as library

Using the following code will get you the user's FB profile picture

```
ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {
    profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }

            }
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. I have added an update under my initial post about my problems.

Comment: Try declaring your profilePictureView outside onclick.. there is a FB login widget profived by FB sdk 

LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);